# Many doubts about decrypt an image file in c

Tags: c, image, fwrite, encryption, fread

Firstly, i'm not very familiarized with C, i come from Java, C#, C++... and possibly i inherited defects from this languages in order to realize this practice, well i have the follows question, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void decrypt(unsigned long* v, unsigned long* k);

const int MAX = 32;
const long delta = 0x9e3779b9;
long sum=0xC6EF3720;

int main() {
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *destino;
  unsigned long v[2];
  unsigned long k[4] = { 128, 129, 130, 131 };
  unsigned long tam=0;
  char* buffer;
  char* aux[sizeof(unsigned long)];
  int i;

if ((fp = fopen("image.png", "rb")) == NULL) {
    printf ("Error! \n ");
    return 0;
}
else {
    fread(&aux,sizeof(unsigned long),1,fp);
    memcpy(&tam,&aux,sizeof(unsigned long));
    buffer = (char*)malloc(tam);
    //fread(&buffer,1,tam,fp);
    char *buffer2[28568];
    fread(&buffer2,1,28568,fp);
    /*for(i = 0;i < tam;++i) {
         printf("%c", ((char *)buffer2)[i]);
     }*/
    for(i=4;i<tam;i+=8) {
        memcpy(&v,&buffer2[i],8);
        decrypt(&v,&k);
    }
    if ((result= fopen("image2.png", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf ("Error! \n ");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        fwrite(v,sizeof(unsigned long)*2,1,result);
        fclose (result);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
return 0;
}

void decrypt(unsigned long* v, unsigned long* k) {
int i=0;
while(i<MAX) {
    v[1] = v[1] -((4 << v[0])+(k[2]^v[0])+(sum^(5 >> v[0]))+k[3]);
    v[0] = v[0] -((4 << v[1])+(k[0]^v[1])+(sum^(5 >> v[1]))+k[1]);
    sum = sum-delta;
    i++;
   }

}
```

Where tam is the size of my binary file (image in this case) where i store first 4 bytes (unsigned long) where is located the size in my png file (28568)

When i create my char* buffer i have to assign dynamically with malloc but when i make a new fread from my file i get a "No source available for "msvrct!memcpy() at 0xrandom_memory_address" from Eclipse when i debug, well, i comment this line and i try to make it manually set a new buffer2 with 28568 as size of my array, apparently works, making a iteration of buffer2 prints ascii characters values but when i call decrypt for make the decryption of my image, the final result is stored in v array which i have to copy in a new file, i tried to search how to make a empty image png in C but i didn't find anything, so i created a copy of my encrypt image calling it "image2.png" but i suppose this not the "clean solution" for that, because for the other hand is not working at all.

For more explanation about this exercise just say that the decrypt funcion work with blocks of 8 bytes (64 bits) that through a key (array k) make a series of operation where they store in v array itself, crossing through the loop 8 in 8 and retrieve the value of buffer in v in each one, after the loop execution we have the result in v and only left to copy in a new file where finally show up the image decrypt.

It's a very complex practice for all of one newbies in C, it's driving my crazy trying to figure out what i doing wrong.

I hope anyone can see what i'm not able to for now.

Comment: Side note: use `malloc` like this: `buffer = malloc(tam * sizeof(*buffer));`. Also, you need to free this memory with `free(buffer);` when you don't need it.

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of `tam` after `memcpy`? Does that match the size of image? `char *buffer[28568]` gets an array of pointers, not an array of `char`, so that's not what you want.

Comment: Try turning the warnings all the way up on your compiler.

Comment: Is it ok to use `char *buffer2[28568];`? I think you should use `char buffer2[28568]`. In the first case you are not creating a buffer for 28568 bytes, but 28568 pointers to char buffers not allocated.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting concepts of pointer, array, and memory allocation, and it hardens your understanding. Consider `char* aux[sizeof(unsigned long)]`, for example. Do you want to alloc `sizeof(unsigned long)` __pointers__ __to__ __char__ or a single char array of `sizeof(unsigned long)` elements?

Comment: about pointers and declarations, C++ and C are not that different... e.g. `char *buffer2[n]` means the same in C and C++: an array of n pointers to char.

Comment: Well, it works fine now, the error was i trying to pass as reference buffer (i was passing the memory address itself) i misunderstanding concepts like array and pointers but for now i'm not getting warnings and problem of memory allocation when assign dynamically the size of my buffer!

Thanks Everybody!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are having problems with the declarations of the buffers. I think the correct should be:

```
FILE *fp;
  FILE *destino;
  unsigned long v[2];
  unsigned long k[4] = { 128, 129, 130, 131 };
  unsigned long tam=0;
  char* buffer;
  char aux[sizeof(unsigned long)]; // without the "*"
  int i;

if ((fp = fopen("image.png", "rb")) == NULL) {
    printf ("Error! \n ");
    return 0;
}
else {
    fread(aux,sizeof(unsigned long),1,fp);
    memcpy(&tam,aux,sizeof(unsigned long));
    buffer = (char*)malloc(tam);
    //fread(buffer,1,tam,fp); // without the "&" in this case
    char buffer2[28568]; // without the "*"
    fread(buffer2,1,28568,fp); // or fread(buffer,1,tam,fp);
    /*for(i = 0;i < tam;++i) {
         printf("%c", buffer2[i]); // or buufer[i] if you change to use it again
     }*/
    for(i=4;i<tam;i+=8) {
        memcpy(v,&buffer2[i],8);
        decrypt(v,k);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks men, that's it the problem, i misinterpreting array concepts with pointers, thanks!

The loop i have to change also buffer for not passing it as reference.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish, but one problem is here:

```
char* aux[sizeof(unsigned long)];
// ... some code ...
fread(&aux,sizeof(unsigned long),1,fp);
```

Understand that `char* aux[sizeof(unsigned long)];` means that you are declaring a double pointer, but `fread()` prototype states that the destination is a single pointer:

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

so what you should be doing instead is:

```
char aux[sizeof(unsigned long)]; 
// ... some code ...
fread(aux,sizeof(unsigned long),1,fp);
```

Don't complicate things that are not complicated!

You also do this mistake in other parts of your code, you need to re-check everything, ok? Again:

```
char *buffer2[28568];
fread(&buffer2,1,28568,fp);
```

should be:

```
char buffer2[28568];
fread(buffer2, 1, 28568, fp);
// or: fread(buffer2, 1, sizeof(buffer2), fp);
```

There are some interesting tutorials on [pointers and arrays](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch2x.htm), I suggest you read some.

Comment: +1 for "Don't complicate things that are not complicated!" :)

Comment: So, an array his behavior is like a pointer, uh? I thought that fread required a pointer in his call to copy the value, that's my thought trying to pass a char* for reference (&) i've done as you say and it works! but not for my buffer that i try to assign dynamically... i think malloc is not working properly well...